# AS3 - Removing event listener failed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

here's my code, i don't know why it doesn't remove the event listener.

What i want to do is having some button to turn the sound on and off according to the beat. On the first click it worked perfectly, but when i want to remove the sound on the second click it cannot remove the event listener.

```
plat.BEAT1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, BEATDown(plat.BEAT1, hihatz, 2));
plat.BEAT2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, BEATDown(plat.BEAT2,cymbalz, 4));    

function BEATDown (padNum, sounz, tiempo) {

    return function (e:TouchEvent) {

        var currentSound:Sound = null;
        var currentSoundChannel:SoundChannel;
        var active:int;

        if (padNum.currentFrame == 1) {
            padNum.gotoAndStop(3);
            padNum.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayBeats);
            active = 1;

        } else {
            padNum.gotoAndStop(1);
            padNum.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayBeats);
            active = 0;
        }

        function playSound(sound:Sound):void
            {

                if (active == 0)
                {
                    // Stop playing ANY sound
                    currentSound = null;
                    currentSoundChannel = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Play a different sound
                    currentSound = sound;
                    currentSoundChannel = sound.play();
                }
            }


        function PlayBeats(event:Event):void
            {

                if (tiempo == 1) {
                    if (fl_SecondsElapsed <= 4) {
                        playSound(sounz);
                    }
                }
                if (tiempo == 2) {
                    if (fl_SecondsElapsed == 1 || fl_SecondsElapsed == 3) {
                        playSound(sounz);
                    }
                }
                if (tiempo == 4) {
                    if (fl_SecondsElapsed == 1) {
                    playSound(sounz);
                }

                }

            }

    }

}
```

EDIT:
The listener i want to remove is **padNum.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayBeats);**
plat.BEAT1 is the button instance. I use multiple instance to trigger different sound, each toggle sound on and off according to the Tiempo count.

Comment: which event listener are you having problems with? The anonymous functions of TOUCH_BEGIN or the ENTER_FRAME listeners?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's because you don't add / remove your listener on the same object; 
is plat.BEAT1 et plat.BEAT2 are the same? I guess not.

I would recommend you to try by adding the EnterFrame listener on stage on this or on the parent element to the if the event is Removed correctly. Then if you want your object works independently, try to target the right object.

```
if (padNum.currentFrame == 1) {
    padNum.gotoAndStop(3);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayBeats);
    active = 1;
} else {
    padNum.gotoAndStop(1);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayBeats);
    active = 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, that's what i wanted to do. though not working, the listener still exist.